# Understanding absolute values in expression parsing to binary tree?

Tags: java, parsing, expression, shunting-yard

I am writing a parser for expressions, which include tokens ),(,|,*,+,-,/, variables and constants.

So far my code works with *,/,-,+,(,), but I do not know how to deal with absolute values.

With parentheses, I start with ( and end with ), which is very simple, but how do I determine which "|" is an opening and which is a closing one?

For parsing I use two stacks and the shunting yard algorithm (or at least the way I understood and wrote it).

Comment: use escape character `\\` for these values.

Comment: @Braj I don't think the OP has issues with using | in his source code, but to parse expressions containing | since this symbol is ambiguous (the same symbol opens and closes expressions).

Comment: What @Zoyd says is correct. I cannot alter a mathematical expression based on my needs. The | is ambiguous and I need to know which opens and which closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some context is needed. If the previous symbol is nothing or one of *,/,-,+,(, the | is opening; otherwise, it is closing.

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I needed to know. Therefore I will simply do a check and if it is one of these tokens or it is the first token it is opening. Thank you very much.